# How do I send autosorted blank rows to the bottom?

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script

I have a script that sorts Column B on edit, but there are two problems with it.

1 - It sends the rows with values to the bottom of the sheet.

2 - The numbers do not sort correctly. They should go in the order of 1,3,4,5,and 20, but when it sorts itself, it orders them as 1, 20, 3, 4, 5. It's like it only recognizes the 2 in 20 and places it after 1.

I've searched forum after forum trying to figure this out with no luck so help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("050")
  var range = sheet.getRange("A6:L200");

 // Sorts by the values in column 2 (B)
 range.sort({column: 2, ascending: true});

}
```

I don't know if this makes a difference or not, but the sheet that's being sorted uses VLOOKUP. Each Column from B on uses VLOOKUP.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A6,data2019,3,FALSE),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's no need to get the blank values in the first place, instead you can use `getDataRange()` to only get the range you need to sort.

Once you've got your range defined, you can sort it. Your values are not being sorted correctly (this is likely due to formatting of the cell from the VLOOKUP). You can simply set the format of the data range to number format using `setNumberFormat('0')` then sort the data to the order you're expecting.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("050");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();

  //sets the formatting of column B to a number in all populated rows
  sheet.getRange(1, 2, numRows).setNumberFormat('0');

  //sorts range by column B using newly formatted values
  range.sort({column: 2, ascending: true});
}
```

Comment: I figured out why the numbers weren't sorting correctly because they weren't formatted properly in the sheet, so I fixed that issue. I only want to sort the cells that aren't blank, but I still need the range to include blank rows for when those rows are automatically updated with values later. Does that make sense?

Comment: @AmandaSnow `var range` is using `getDataRange()` which should pick up on any new data that has been added to the sheet. Will the new data be added in random rows in the sheet or just the next empty row?